# Angular filter by date range

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am working on an AngularJS project where I am making an HTTP call from a service to a restful API and getting results as objects containing a date in the format of YYYY-MM-DD.

Now I want to fetch these results by ng-repeat but want to be able to display them according to month. Here is the code:

```
user
            .userControll(moneyvm.userProfile)
            .then(function(response){
                if(response.data.error_on === true){
                    moneyvm.showStatments = false;
                }
                else if(response.data.success_on    ===     true){
                    moneyvm.showStatments = true;

                    // checking whether user does have income statements.
                    if(response.data.results.length > 0){
                        moneyvm.hasIncomes      =       true;


                        moneyvm.monthlyIncomes  =   response.data.results;

                        console.log(moneyvm.monthlyIncomes);

                    }
                    else{
                        moneyvm.hasIncomes      =       false;  
                    }

                }
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                alert(err);
            })
```

Here I have a user service (user) and userControll method display the all statements. My html is as follow:

```
   <ul class="list monthly-income-list">
           <li class="pull-left" ng-repeat="income in moneyvm.monthlyIncomes">
                    {{income }}
           </li>
   </ul>
```

I want to be able to filter this list like this {{income | filter: "01-01-2017" : "01-31-2017"}}, where this should give me all January transactions, so far I don't have much luck with this.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please more elaborate the solution, what exactly you want?

Comment: I have bootstrap tabs from January to December. When user clicks a particular tab (for example December), I want to filter my results and only display results for December month. Since I am getting all statements when page loads, So I just want a way to filter them in different tab. Cheers mate.